# Profiling a Mule ESB application

Tags: java, mule, mule-studio, yourkit

The [documentation](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Profiling+Mule) that Mulesoft provides to help install the YourKit and use it to profile a Mule application is not very helpful.

I went as far to install YourKit and integrate it into MuleStudio. When trying to set up a profile configuration, it asks for me an entry point for the Java Application (Main class). 
I am not quiet sure what is the entry point, as I simply just right click the flow diagram and click 'Run As -> Mule Application'

Is there any better manual to help figure out how to profile a Mule application?

Comment: Are you profiling an application running in your local mule studio?

Comment: @genjosanzo Yes, I am trying to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To profile your mule applications running in your local Studio using yourkit no particular configuration is needed.

You simply start yourkit and select the application named ApplicationDeployer